# how to sort a series with positive value in assending order and negative value in descending order

Tags: pandas

I have a series `tt=pd.Series([-1,5,4,0,-7,-9])` .Now i want to sort 'tt'.

the positive values sort  in assending order and negative values sort in descending order.Positive values is in front of negative values.

I want to get the following result.

```
4,5,0,-1,-7,-9
```

Is there a good way to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit too extended but it gets you your desired output:

```
import pandas as pd

tt=pd.Series([-1,5,4,0,-7,-9])

pd.concat((tt[tt > 0].sort_values(ascending=True), tt[tt <= 0].sort_values(ascending=False)))

Out[1]: 
0    4
1    5
2    0
3   -1
4   -7
5   -9
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Abdou.Thanks,the answer helps.

Answer (score 2):

You want to sort on `tt <= 0` first.  Notice this is `True` for negatives and zero, `False` for positives.  Sorting on this puts positives first.  Then sort on `tt.abs()`.  This puts the smallest sized numbers first.

```
df = pd.concat([tt, tt.abs(), tt.le(0)], axis=1)
df.sort_values([2, 1])[0]

2    4
1    5
3    0
0   -1
4   -7
5   -9
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks for your solution.the approach is very novel.